# subl command is not displaying any output on RHEL in virtual machine

Tags: sublimetext3, virtualbox

I have installed sublime_text on RHEL in virtualBox .It is not GUI based.
Steps used to install sublime are as follows:

- sudo rpm -v --import https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-rpm-pub.gpg
- sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.sublimetext.com/rpm/stable/x86_64/sublime-text.repo
- sudo yum install sublime-text

Comment: I'm fairly sure sublime text requires a running GUI...?

Comment: VirtualBox is installed on macOs that is GUI based but RHEL on virtual box is cli based only